SwiftUI macOS: Center the default filename label in DocumentGroup when using NavigationSplitView
I'm working on a macOS SwiftUI app that uses DocumentGroup to handle document-based functionality. By default, DocumentGroup provides a filename editing label, which appears centered at the top of the window when the content is displayed without any container.
However, when I wrap my content inside a NavigationSplitView, the filename label shifts to the left, losing its centered alignment. I want this label to stay centered within the NavigationSplitView.
Below is the code:
   DocumentGroup(newDocument: AmberDocument()) { file in
    DashboardView()
            .preferredColorScheme(colorScheme)
    }



struct DashboardView: View {

// MARK: - Properties
@Binding var document: AmberDocument

// MARK: - Body
var body: some View {
    NavigationSplitView {
        SectionPanelView()
            .frame(minWidth: 200, idealWidth: 220)
#if os(macOS)

        .toolbar(removing: .sidebarToggle)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .primaryAction) {
                Spacer()

                Button(action: toggleSidebar, label: {
                    Image(systemSymbol: .sidebarLeading)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 20)
                        .foregroundColor(.textSecondary)
                })
                .buttonStyle(.plain)
            }
        }
#endif
        } content: {
            TextEditor(text: $document.text)
        } detail: {
            NotesPanelView()
        }
        .navigationSplitViewStyle(.balanced)
        .background(.ultrathick)
        .removeFocusOnTap()
    }
}

Current UI SS - 
Expected UI SS - 
I would be grateful for any suggestions.
Thanks.
